# How can I change playback speed of mpv video player?

Tags: video, mpv

I love `mpv player` for it's modern minimalist look, easy moving along a video simply with mouse scroll and robust rendering of `.mp4` videos.

However I could not figure out how to change playback speed as I can do easily in vlc playback menu. I simply can not see any GUI option to do so. Nor could I find a relevant configuration trick in the [wiki](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/wiki/FAQ).

So appreciate your hints if there is a hidden button or a config tweak to define a shortcut key to do so.  I'm using mpv on Ubuntu `18.04`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Are there shortcut keys to change the playback speed in mpv?

You need to refer to the [manual](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#keyboard-control):

> The reference manual lists all the options and configuration options mpv understands, key bindings, scripting, and other customizations.

Use the following keys:

> <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd>
> Decrease/increase current playback speed by 10%.
>
> <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd>
> Halve/double current playback speed.
>
> <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
> Reset playback speed to normal.

Comment: Is there a way to change those 10% to a different value (like 50%)?

Comment: @icl7126 you can by creating custom shortcuts in your `input.conf` file: `<key> add speed 0.25` or `<key> add speed -0.25` will make those keys change speed by 0.25 instead of 0.10.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamHankiewicz Yes, [here is the whole list of supported commands](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpv-player/mpv/master/etc/input.conf). I've actually bought bluetooth NumPad and re-assign keys to change speed to specific values, like `KP1 set speed 2.0`.